# Does the eod bot count as an enemy vehicle for the "It goes Boom" assignment?

Tags: battlefield-3

In Battle Field 3 the "It goes boom" assignment says that I need to destroy an enemy vehicle with the repair torch.

I was wondering if destroying an enemy EOD bot with the repair torch counts towards this assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although I haven't done this myself. However the discussions in the forum posts below all confirm that it counts.

**[Source 1](http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/battlefield-3/1461357-tips-complete-goes-boom-assignment.html), [Source 2](http://over30clan.forumotion.com/t2877-bf3-assignemtns-it-goes-boom-made-easy), [Source 3](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654347804944286/)**

Comment: I can't confirm or deny this, but you might want to check and make sure this is still true. Some "tricks" like this have been patched (I noticed none of the sources are newer than February)

Comment: @SSumner you're right which is why I was a little dubious about posting an answer :P I'll check this out when I can or if someone else could confirm that would be great :)